# How to increase productivity with slow startup time in frameworks like Spring Boot and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, tdd

I am trying out Hibernate and noticed that the startup time is roughly 4500ms on my laptop.

Spring boot for example also takes ~7000ms to startup, if you have the most basic spring-JPA and web-MVC set up.

How are developers supposed to do prototyping or TDD in Java, if after every code change I have to wait five seconds?

How much faster do dynamic language start up?

For example, how long does a single persist statement in Python's SQLAlchemy take?

I understand that in real-world applications startup takes way longer, and updates or tests are performed remotely with a CI/CD server. But I'm still in the learning phase and for now I like to be able to see my output after minor code changes.

Comment: Why would think that dynamic languages would start up faster? Java is not exactly great in this regard but I suspect it is Spring and Hibernate that are to blame. That or you have a mechanical disk drive. Also, TDD wise, if you need to talk to your DB to run unit tests they are not unit tests.

Comment: Look at things like JRebel.

Comment: @AluanHaddad  no compilation time? But I don't know how long Java compilation takes.

Comment: Java compiles quickly. Besides all code must ultimately get compiled before it can run, it is just a question of when.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel JRebel is proprietary, and does it even work when dependency injection or sessions are introduced?

Comment: @YoshuaNahar That tool works allows you to hotswap java classes. I have yet to something it can't do. But yes, it is proprietary, and not something that a person "just learning things" would want to invest into. But one can ask for a trial licence. But I think this is the wrong path here.

Comment: Additionally, there are some way to do hotswapping in Spring Boot:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Oke, I'll look into it.

Comment: @GhostCat I got a trial licence at JRebel and I have to say it is a great tool. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sure. Beyond that; is there anything I could do to make my answer upvote/accept worty in your eyes? (take your time thinking, I already hit the daily limit today; so when you come to a positive decision, at least me; I can wait until tomorrow ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Oke. You talk about how TDD is supposed to be done, I understand completely what your saying but that wasn't my question. I wanted to know how I, as a beginner to Spring Boot or Hibernate, can better explore these large frameworks by just trying things out without waiting so long. You know,  like how back in your starting days as a programmer you restarted your (command line) app after every println or if statement :')

Comment: I think I got that part ... and I agree: these expensive startup times make it hard to "just play around" with such frameworks. Believe me - as our stack (with Tomcat on top of it) can take 20 minutes to start; and then requires another 15 minutes to get the underlying system in an "now i can test stuff" state, I value JRebel very much.

Comment: Oh oke. I understand. What I'm looking for does not exist, and I should look into hotswapping and tools like JRebel. Got it. I will come back tomorrow to accept your answer, as what I'm asking can't be done any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a misconception on your end. The main focus of TDD are **unit tests**. Of course, TDD is a great concept, but the point is: you want those quick feedback loops.

Thus you use it to write **unit** tests. Tests that work on a small, isolated unit. Tests that have **zero** dependencies on anything else but *your* compiled classes and JUnit/TestNG/... other test related frameworks.

You write a test (5, 10 lines of code); you write production code (probably not much more than that). Run, write new test, or fix production code ...

And then; when you are **convinced** that all your *units* do what they are supposed to do; then you start looking into writing "functional" or "integration" tests that require your whole stack to be up and running.